# GWT, runAsync and server-side code delivery prevention?

Tags: gwt

I use gwt-platform and CodeSplitting. Now I'd like to make it impossible for users to fetch the async JS-code if they're not logged in.

In other words: If GWT tries to fetch some JS-code 'cause of code-splitting. The server should check if the user is logged in and only then send the client the JS-code.

Is this possibility given with GWT? Or is there some plugin available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a file access problem which is related to your web server & not GWT application, because code splitting only breaks down your code for on-demand loading & does not offer any mechanism for access control to the broken parts of your js code (deffered js).
So if you want to prevent access to those files, you should integrate your login mechanism with your web server.

Comment: The login-mechanism is server side. But we'd like to have some kind of servlet running on the server that has the ability to NOT upload the deferred JS-code to the client. It's just one aspect of maximizing security of our application ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this on the backend. 
For example in Spring Security you can define that specific resources (i.e code splitting fragments) can only be loaded when there is a valid principal (logged in user).
However I am not sure why you really want to do that (protect your client side code?)?

Comment: The reason is simply to minimize the possibilities of an attack. We don't use any specific server Framework. It's just plain Java, GWT and Tomcat